# Ruby clicking a table header when the header is not visible on the page

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, html-table, automation

I'm using ruby for automation testing purposes, playback using Chrome. I'm trying to click a table header when the header is not visible on the page (it's a typical HTML table, with THEAD, TR, TH etc.) However, when I try to interact with the element I get the below:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600233 
(523efee95e3d68b8719b3a1c83051aa63aa6b10d),platform=Linux 4.15.0-43-generic x86_64)
```

What I need to do is to scroll to that element so that it is in view.

Comment: Could you show a bit more code? How do you want to interact with it? Why is it not visible on the page - not loaded, maybe selenium is on the wrong page?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Clicking an invisible element is supposed to fail – imagine an actual user trying to click a table header when it's not there. That's hardly possible.

Comment: The purpose is to scroll to the element so that it is in view. Work around was to use a javascript call:

page.execute_script %{document.getElementById("my_id").scrollIntoView();}

Answer (score 0):

Javascript call within Ruby used as a workaround:

```
page.execute_script %{
    document.getElementById("my_id").scrollIntoView();
}
```